# How to log out from the DevPortal in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store-connect

I use to code using someone else's developer account. 
I would now like to use xcode to manage my own certficates (and my own Apple ID), and make requests to my dev portal account, but it seems it remembered the old credentials and won't let me enter my new ones. Someone may know a way to log out ? Moreover, it keeps downloading the dev identities from the older account, and won't let me suppress them. Any chance some might help ?

Comment: Very interesting issue. May be you should cleanup a keychain?

Comment: Tried to delete them already, they seem to be synced again

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the old certs using Keychain access.
Remove the old provisioning profiles in Xcode -> Organizer

Go through the process of getting new certs and download the new provisioning profiles from developer.apple.com (the Provisioning Portal).

Change the signing properties of the project to match.